# How I convert AS3 to Haxe?

Tags: html, actionscript-3, cross-compiling, haxe

I have a Flash game on facebook and i  have many class and many animation on FLA and I want to convert Haxe.

Actionscript 3.0 to Haxe Is it possible to directly convert ? or (converter, plugin...)

Or Do you have any advice how I convert my game ?

What is the best way ?

Comment: HAXE is a programming language. You can convert your AS3 class to HAXE, sure (actually, you can convert your AS3 class to many other languages either). What would be the point of that?

Comment: @Organis I want my as3 code convert haxe and html5

Comment: Then just converting to HAXE won't help you much because HTML5 does not support FLA/SWF graphics format.

Comment: @Organis I understand, okey thanks!

Comment: OpenFL has the ability to ingest SWF assets, even when outputting to HTML5. -- though it has limits depending on whether there is code in them: http://www.openfl.org/learn/haxelib/tutorials/using-swf-assets/ But importing SWF graphics & animations works fine. I've done it myself: https://twitter.com/Jeff__Ward/status/715999323570487300

Comment: @JeffWard I convert my all source code now. But I don't know how i manage my FLA animations to HTML5 ? I use openFL or ?

Comment: @timJefrrey Create a thread in the OpenFL community forum for more specific help: http://community.openfl.org/

Comment: @Organis if your going to port AS3 to any language then Haxe is the most worthwhile from a simplicity and usability, it's not uncommon to mix Haxe & AS3 in the same flash project. AS3 can easily mapped to Haxe ( reverse not always true ) so decoupled game logic becomes delimited.  See JeffWard's comments as starting point. OpenFL and NME support js SWF animation, frame commands need extra code. Porting: JS would loose all the typing,Typescript loose some of the typing.  Haxe is not yet mainstream so it's versitility is underestimated by small companies that follow, but otherwise it's on point.

Answer (score 6):

Use the official converter from the HaxeFoundation: https://github.com/HaxeFoundation/as3hx

Use a rendering / game engine like OpenFL: http://www.openfl.org

This should cover most of the logic, you'd still need to go through everything and make sure your logic is still sound.

Comment: As a side note, I've done conversions with great success with old projects / libraries. The converter does most of the heavy lifting, but ultimately you need to give everything a once over. Some pieces of logic doesn't translate well and will require some intervention.

Comment: @timJefrrey Here's a nice case study video you can watch where FlowPlay talks about their experience while porting AS3 to Haxe: https://haxe.org/videos/conferences/haxe-summit-us-2018/deep-dive-on-porting-actionscript-to-haxe-scott-pultz.html